# Is it possible to use a variable number in the name of a variable name?

Tags: c#, wpf, variables

(using WPF)
Is it possible to use the number of a `TextBox` to select the parameter name?
For example, the user can put 0,1,2 or 3 as text in the `TextBox`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int test = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    string nr1 = "this string is 1";
    string nr2 = "this string is 2";
    string nr3 = "this string is 3";

    MessageBox.Show();
}
```

Now for `MessageBox.Show();` in want to put something as `nr(test)`
Would something like this be possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I suspect there is a much better way to handle your actual problem.

Comment: I was thinking for using it as a methode for when i use whole sets of text strings. Set X lines 1 to 10 etc. As i am not an advanced programmer i had no idea how else to do this in a better way.

Comment: Why not use `string[]` or `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It sounds like you want some form of numerical representation of your text boxes, then use the Tag property and give the numerical order you want to give them. Then you can write string val = "Text box " + ((TextBox)sender).Tag.ToString() + "Contains text " + ((TextBox)sender).Text; The event has to be a text box event, not button click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) ?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
dict.Add(1,"String Number 1");
dict.Add(2,"String Number 2");
dict.Add(3,"String Number 3");

int test = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
MessageBox.Show(dict[test]);
```

Comment: Do i understand correct when i say this is almost simular to a list, only a list is always set to [numbers] and a dicttionary can also be names/strings ?

Comment: @Dante Correct. Note that your real code will need to handle exceptions from `int.Parse()` (or use `int.TryParse()`). Also, you will need to use [`Dictionary.TryGetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) to ensure that the number is really in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int test = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            string[] nr = new string[3]{"this string is 1","this string is 2","this string is 3"};
            MessageBox.Show(nr[test-1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Dictionary<int,string>` with all the data you want handled by keys:

```
MessageBox.Show(myDict[test])
```

Here you can see the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [FindName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx)

lets suggest this:

### XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox2" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23"  Name="textBox3" Width="120" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23"  Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

your could would look like this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int number =2;
        TextBox tb = this.FindName(string.Format("textBox{0}", number)) as TextBox;

        MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a dictionary. Dealing with dictionaries simplifies your life. I suggest looking [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary).